# What is the equivalent capacitive load seen by the IC if in a datasheet of a chip CLmax=10nF given and I connect an RC filter as a load?

Tags: capacitor, analog, datasheet, load, passive-filter

I have a stupid question where in the quick, the answer does not come into my mind.

If in a datasheet of an integrated circuit, a maximum load capacitance is given, e.g. 10nF, and I want to connect an RC low pass filter to it, how to size the components R and C (for a fixed cut-off frequency) in order to not violate the datasheet specification?

Comment: What IC? what pin? if it's a timeconstant no.

Comment: Use a unity-gain buffer (voltage-follower op-amp).  The overlap between "ICs sensitive enough to load capacitance to list it" and "ICs that will fail if directly connected to an R-C filter" is nearly 100%.  So connect it indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect an RC filter the equivalent circuit is R in series with C.

CLmax is specified because the load of a digital output is supposed to be a digital input which is a capacitive load (the gate to source capacitor).

If the load of that digital output is an RC filter than C may exceed the value of CLmax.

Comment: And exactly, that's the point of my question: How to calculate R and C values to NOT exceed the CLmax ??

Comment: I assume that CLmax = 10nF. To answer your question I should know the value of the output resistance of that pin. If, for example, the output resistance of that pin is 5 Ohms, than you have an upper limit of RC. Let's call this limit RCmax = (5 * 10) (Ohm * nF). That means that if you add an external resistance of 50 Ohms than your CL can be 100 nF. If you add an external resistance of 500 Ohms, than CL can be 1000 nF and so on.

Comment: Ok, that's a good hint, thanks Enrico! Unfortunately the value of the output resistance is not known, it's just specified CL = 10nF max. And now?

Comment: You should estimate it by the absolute maximum ratings or by a direct measure. If you don't wanna waste time, assume 20 Ohms as a reasonable value of the output resistance of a digital output pin.

Comment: I also thought about measuring but unfortunately I still don't have this chip in my hands. Ok, that's a nice estimate starting value, thanks a lot Enrico!